# How to create a unit test that tests that a page requires authorization in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to work out how to write a unit test that will test that a controllers authorization is working. IE a user that is not logged in can't access the page. Does anybody know how to go about this? I am having trouble finding examples.

something like this (Pseudo Code)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Get_Auth_Page()
    {
        be_a_user_thats_not_logged_in = true;

        // Arrange
        MyController controller = new MyController();

        // Act
        var result = controller.Index();

        // Assert
        if(result.httpstatus == 403)
            Assert.True();
    }
```

Comment: You will probably want to mock the HttpContext and related Identity. Also, see this: http://www.sharpedgesoftware.com/Blog/2011/03/14/mocking-a-controllercontext-with-authenticated-user-with-moq-for-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: Please remember to check the helpful descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply decorating your action method with `[Authorize]`, you can just have a test that asserts the existence of the attribute:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index_action_requires_authentication()
{
    // If Index is overloaded, you might need to filter by argument list
    MethodInfo indexMethod = typeof(MyController).GetMethod("Index");

    bool requiresAuthentication = 
        Attribute.IsDefined(indexMethod, typeof(AuthorizeAttribute));

    Assert.IsTrue(requiresAuthentication);
}
```

Obviously you aren't testing the Authorize *implementation* here, but it does serve to both document and to protect against developers accidentally removing it.

If you are running custom code, then you are probably returning a `HttpStatusCodeResult`, so you can just check for that:

```
public void Index_action_requires_authentication()
{
    ActionResult result = new MyController().Index();

    HttpStatusCodeResult statusCodeResult = result as HttpStatusCodeResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(statusCodeResult);
    Assert.AreEqual(403, statusCodeResult.StatusCode);
}
```

If you are manually writing to the HttpResponse (Response.StatusCode or Response.Headers), then you'll need to mock the `HttpContextBase` as others have described.